# Is Cygwin 2.0.2 supported on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cygwin, windows-server-2016, cygwin-x

I need some small clarification on Cygwin and Windows compatibility.

Is cygwin 2.0.2 compatible with Windows Server 2016? Or do  need to get the latest version of Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is cygwin 2.0.2 compatible with Windows Server 2016?

From the [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.what.supported):

> Cygwin can be expected to run on all modern, released versions of Windows. State January 2016 this includes Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and all later versions of Windows up to Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. The 32 bit version of Cygwin also runs in the WOW64 32 bit environment on released 64 bit versions of Windows, the 64 bit version of course only on 64 bit Windows.
>
> Keep in mind that Cygwin can only do as much as the underlying OS supports. Because of this, Cygwin will behave differently, and exhibit different limitations, on the various versions of Windows.

So, in theory, Cygwin 2.0.2-1 **should** work, however, read on ...

---

#### Do I need to get the latest version of Cygwin on Windows Server 2016?

[Windows Server 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2016) was released on 26 September 2016.

You have also tagged your question [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10). [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) was released on July 29, 2015.

Cygwin [2.0.2-1](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-05/msg00022.html) was released on Fri, 08 May 2015.

```
From: Yaakov Selkowitz <yselkowitz at cygwin dot com>
To: cygwin-announce <cygwin-announce at cygwin dot com>
Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 18:29:52 -0500
Subject: Updated: Cygwin 2.0.2-1
Authentication-results: sourceware.org; auth=none
Reply-to: The Cygwin Mailing List <cygwin at cygwin dot com>

The following packages have been updated in the Cygwin distribution:

* cygwin-2.0.2-1
* cygwin-devel-2.0.2-1
```

Source [Yaakov Selkowitz - Updated: Cygwin 2.0.2-1](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-05/msg00022.html)

It is likely that Cygwin 2.0.2-1 will have bugs that prevent it working correctly on any Windows OS released after Fri, 08 May 2015, which includes Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10.

So you probably should use the latest version. There will have been many enhancements and bug fixes since May 2015.

> The most recent version of the Cygwin DLL is [2.10.0](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2018-02/msg00002.html).

Source [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

```
From: Corinna Vinschen <corinna-cygwin at cygwin dot com>
To: cygwin-announce at cygwin dot com
Date: Fri, 2 Feb 2018 15:38:09 +0100
Subject: Updated: Cygwin 2.10.0-1
Authentication-results: sourceware.org; auth=none
Reply-to: The Cygwin Mailing List <cygwin at cygwin dot com>

Hi folks,

I uploaded a new Cygwin release 2.10.0-1
```

Source [Corinna Vinschen - Updated: Cygwin 2.10.0-1](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2018-02/msg00002.html)

Comment: Thank you so much DavidPostill for the detailed information.

Comment: @veeru Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).

Comment: Once again thanks @DavidPostill for providing detailed information.